# oracle subquery in where clause with order by

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I'm trying to get a customer's address with these rules:

1. Get preferred address if it exists (preferred_ind = 'Y')
2. If multiple preferred addresses, get first one (max(address_id) is fine)
3. If no preferred addresses, then just get first one (max(address_id) is fine, again.)
4. If no addresses, just return customer name with no address info.
5. preferred_ind can be 'Y', 'N' or null.

   ```
   SELECT c.first_name,
          c.last_name,
          a.address_line_1,
          a.city,
          a.state_code,
          a.postal_code
   FROM my_customer c,
        my_customer_address a
   WHERE c.customer_id = a.customer_id(+)
   AND (a.address_id IS NULL OR a.address_id = (SELECT MAX(a2.address_id)
                                                FROM my_customer_address a2
                                                WHERE a2.customer_id = c.customer_id
                                                ORDER BY nvl(a2.preferred_ind, 'N') DESC));
   ```

But, of course, Oracle doesn't allow for the ORDER BY in a subquery. So how can I get the results I want?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rewrite to ANSI Outer Join syntax and apply a ROW_NUMBER:

```
--untested
SELECT c.first_name,
       c.last_name,
       a.address_line_1,
       a.city,
       a.state_code,
       a.postal_code
FROM my_customer c
LEFT JOIN 
 (
   SELECT customer_id,
       address_line_1,
       city,
       state_code,
       postal_code,
       ROW_NUMBER() 
       OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id
             ORDER BY preferred_ind = 'Y' DESC, address_id DESC) AS rn
   FROM my_customer_address
 ) a
ON c.customer_id = a.customer_id
AND a.rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, dnoeth. That was it! Just some minor issues:
1) I think you meant "LEFT OUTER JOIN", right?
2) PARTITION is misspelled.
3) You forgot the right parenthesis before the "as rn"

Comment: Fixed my answer, but OUTER is optional, most people simple right LEFT/RIGHT JOIN...